# the error about run sudo R CMD javareconf

Tags: java, r, macos

I wanna reconfigure my jdk, so I installed jdk from https://www.oracle.com/.

However, when I ran `sudo  R CMD javareconf` in my mac terminal, here was the error:

> 'jni.h' file not found.

How can i solve the problem? I am so confused.

[image]

my laptop is mac pro M2, and I have installed the java and jdk. The java version is java version "1.8.0_381".

Comment: Have you followed the platform-specific instructions in the installation manual? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-admin.html#Java-_0028macOS_0029

Comment: Do not use images for code or logs in Stackoverflow.